# Converting a char array to a IPv6 address in C#?

Tags: c#, sql-server

I have numbers stored in a SQL Server `char(39)` field that I need to convert to a IPv6 IPAddress?

Examples

```
281470698521600
281470698522623
58569107296622255421594597096899477504 
58569107375850417935858934690443427839
```

I don't know much about IPv6 but I'm assuming I can ping the address to verify it is correct. I could do with some help converting it from a number though? The examples seem short, are they missing subnetting?

Comment: What have you tried? Where did you get stuck?

Comment: I've converted bigint to IPv4 addresses using `IPAddress ip = new IPAddress(convertedNumber);` after check `BitConverter.IsLittleEndian`. I'm currently reading up on how IPv6 works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The number has to be made into a hex string (12 characters) and then separate the character into groups of 2 characters with a colon between each group.  Here is sample code

```
string input = "281470698521600";
string hex = long.Parse(input).ToString("x");
string[] array = hex.ToCharArray()
    .Select((x, i) => new { chr = x, index = i })
    .GroupBy(x => x.index / 2)
    .Select(x => x.First().chr.ToString() + x.Last().chr.ToString())
    .ToArray();
string IPV6 = string.Join(":", array);
```

The output would be this : ff:ff:01:00:04:00